# Remote Access to Windows Folders from Mac

Tags: windows, macos, remote-access

Is there a way to remotely access network folders from Windows on a Mac? I tried using TeamViewer but the network folders appear empty on Mac.

I am not using Remote Desktop Client as it has a restriction for the System to be awake.

Comment: Does the network folder go wrong when you use the remote access client?  If it does, then the network folder itself or the sharing settings may be wrong so you need to check that. If not, then maybe TeamViewer's problem, try to replace another remote access tool.

Comment: Can you clarify if the Windows system is sleeping?  Based on your question its unclear if you mean the Windows system is operating or sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

A good article [here](http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/20/map-a-network-drive-on-a-mac/)

> From the Mac OS X Finder
>
> 1. Type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+K to bring up the 'Connect to Server' window.
> 2. Enter the path to the network drive you want to map, ie:
>      `smb://networkcomputer/networkshare` and click 'Connect'
> 3. Enter your login/password and click “OK” to mount the network drive.